Is it possible to implement RAII with Python in the context of ensuring that the close() function is called on opened files?
I asked a question earlier today, Is it important to call close() on an file opened with open() if flush() is called after each write() operation?
I asked this question while thinking about data loss, something which flush() would account for. However, there are other reasons why properly calling close() is a good idea.

Calling close() allows a resource (file handle) to be freed, rather than relying on the OS to do it.
It is also good design and good practice to write code which puts things back as it found them. If nothing else, it is what future readers of code expect to see. So better to not confuse them.

My question is, if we want to manage a file using an object (a class), is there a way to implement RAII like behaviour?
In a language without GC, such as C++, this would be done with a combination of class destructor functions and scope. Destructors are automatically called by the compiler at the end of scope.
Python doesn't have such a mechanism. It only has one way of expressing RAII, and that is with the with syntax (Context Managers):
with open(example_filename, 'w') as ofile:
    ofile.write()

Is there a way to write a class which manages a resource in a RAII like manner in Python?
One possible way to do it might be to pass a context manager to a class __init__.
class ResourceManager():
    def __init__(self, file):
        self._file = file
    def write():
        self._file.write(f'hello world\n')
        self._file.flush()

with open(example_filename, 'w') as ofile:
    manager = ResourceManager(ofile)
    manager.write()
    manager.write()
    manager.write()


While doing some background reading on what a context manager actually is, I found an exact example of how to implement RAII to manage a resource like a file.
The full article containing the example can be found at realpython.
Here's how to do it:

To create a Context Manager, implement the special dunder methods __enter__ and __exit__
A class which implements these methods can be used as a Context Manager from within a with statement

class FileContextManager():
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self._filename = filename

    def __enter__(self):
        self._file = open(self._filename, 'w')
        return self._file

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self._file.flush()
        self._file.close()

with FileContextManager(example_path) as file:
    file.write(f'hello world\n')

This demonstrates how to define a class which performs RAII like behaviour in combination with the with statement.

i think it's better to link to the real docs than to third-party sites: contextlib

This FileContextManager class looks like a useless wrapper. I've learnt absolutely nothing from this question and answer. If you think you have valuable info to tell or show, please clarify your problem and/or solution.

I mean, you already had a class that works with the with statement... the file object is a context manager.

I thought it was obvious that this class isn't the complete story and that the intention is to provide a mechanism to create something which uses a file. This is obvious, no?
